# Attach Android SDK sources in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-source

I want to see Android SDK source code in order to understand how it works.

How can I attach Android SDK sources in eclipse?

Comment: Newer question with better answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620294/source-attachment-for-android-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: These days if you use Android Studio, the sourcecode is automatically attached and you can go into any API declaration right from the editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For newer releases**

This is the only way to do it for the newer releases of the SDK:

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

It can take a little bit, but once you get it set up, it is easy to repeat for later releases.  You will notice too that it helps solve the problem of the autocomplete lagging in Eclipse as well!  Well worth it in and of itself...

**For older releases**

You need to download some source files specific to which Android API version you are working with.

The URL is

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+archive/<API version>.tar.gz
```

And you have to replace  with one of these:

- gingerbread-release for API 9 – Android 2.3
- froyo-release for API 8 – Android 2.2
- eclair-release for API 7 – Android 2.1
- donut-release for API 6 – Android 1.6

so the URL becomes for example:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+archive/froyo-release.tar.gz
```

for froyo, or:

```
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+archive/gingerbread-release.tar.gz
```

**How to fix the autocomplete lagging problem once and for all**

After you have downloaded the file, (which comes as .tar.gz by the way), you have to open the archive, and copy the contents of the base directory, into your

```
<android-SDK>\platforms\android-<API version>\sources
```

directory. (Create the sources directory if it does not exist)

When you now start Eclipse, you should have autocompletion working fine again!

Comment: Thanks also for autocomplete problem, I noticed that too.

Comment: Make sure to check the last step

Comment: This solution is no longer the easy solution. It will waste a large amount of bandwidth and disk space. If you are simply browsing the source with eclipse, the better solution is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620294/source-attachment-for-android-jar-in-eclipse

Answer (score 3):

There is even an Eclipse plugin for that - [Android Sources](http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/).

However I just downloaded the plugin jar (~200 MB) and extracted sources from it. Then in Eclipse I attached the sources by going to my Android project, selecting `android.jar` > `Properties` > `Java Source Attachment` > `External Folder`.

Comment: At least for API version 10 and below.  Still a nice find.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody still needs that crusty old Gingerbread framework code, it can still be found in the depths of the Android source tree:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+archive/gingerbread/core/java.tar.gz