# Problems with ExtAudioRecorder on Android

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am using ExtAudioRecorder from http://i-liger.com/article/android-wav-audio-recording to record WAV files for further audio processing. However, sometimes I get this set of error messages:

```
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{musicscoreify.app/musicscoreify.app.ReadWavFile}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at musicscoreify.app.ReadWavFile.onCreate(ReadWavFile.java:138)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
12-08 18:58:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(7323):     ... 11 more
```

because one of the methods in ExtAudioRecorder crashed. The method is as follows:

```
public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder)
        {
            audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); // Fill buffer
            try
            { 
                randomAccessWriter.write(buffer); // Write buffer to file
                payloadSize += buffer.length;
                if (bSamples == 16)
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<buffer.length/2; i++)
                    { // 16bit sample size
                        short curSample = getShort(buffer[i*2], buffer[i*2+1]);
                        if (curSample > cAmplitude)
                        { // Check amplitude
                            cAmplitude = curSample;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else    
                { // 8bit sample size
                    for (int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (buffer[i] > cAmplitude)
                        { // Check amplitude
                            cAmplitude = buffer[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Error occured in updateListener, recording is aborted");
                //stop();
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have a similar problem? I have no idea why the recording will be aborted and why does it only happens at certain times. Since there is no pattern (or at least I didn't realise if there is a pattern) to the occurrence of the bug, it makes it rather difficult for me to debug. It would be great if someone can help me out on this.

Comment: Is this line problem  `audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);`?
If yes, you AudioRecord object wasn't initialized

Comment: I think the problem lies with the code in the try block because I always see "Error occured in updateListener, recording is aborted" when the error occurs.

Comment: What is 138th line in ReadWavFile.java?

Comment: It's the processing of what to output to an XML file after the recording has been successfully recorded. Unfortunately, the recording has some problems.

Comment: I always get this exception "Error occured in updateListener, recording is aborted" when I have problems with recording the audio. The exception is caught by onPeriodicNotification().

Comment: Put a breakpoint on start of onPeriodicNotification(). Then run program line by line and try to find out which line is problem.

Comment: I get this error message "The JAR file C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\android.jar has no source attachment." which I don't understand what it means exactly. It occurs when the debug point is at "randomAccessWriter.write(buffer); // Write buffer to file".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620294/source-attachment-for-android-jar-in-eclipse