# Source not found ClassLoader.class when invoking an activity from main

Tags: android

I have been trying to invoke another activity from the mainactivity class with the code:

```
startActivity(new Intent("intent filter name here"));
```

However when I debug the application when it gets to this line I get a source not found message in the class file editor that says the source attachment does not contain the source for the file ClassLoader.class. There is an option to change the attached source "android.jar" but there is only one such file under the_targetAPI folder. How can i fix this?

Comment: I have found a solution to this problem at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620294/source-attachment-for-android-jar-in-eclipse .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And don't forget to add it to `manifest.xml`.

By upper error also try to clean or rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Intent from one activity to another:

```
Intent ii=new Intent(Firstactivity.this,Secondactivity.class);
startActivity(ii);
```

Import tis one :

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

Add both classes in your Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.task.secondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

---

Try this one , its may work.  check the manfest.xml ,

```
Source not found ClassLoader.class when invoking an activity from main
```

this may be the reason. check it out :)
Happy coding :)