# Alarm Manager doesnot work?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, background-service

I am simply trying to implement the AlarmManager. I wrote the code for alarm manager but the code doesnot work. AlarmManager doesnot fire the Broadcast Receiver and service. But when I donot use the AlarmManager and simply start the service using intent the service run. How to make AlarmManager work to schedule the service periodically?
Below is the code:

*MainActivity.java*

```
package com.alarmmanager;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pending =PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm =(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),15000,pending);       
    }
}
```

*AlarmReceiver.java*

```
package com.alarmmanager;

import android.content.*;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        intent =new Intent(context,MainService.class);
        context.startService(intent);

    }
}
```

*MainService.java*

```
package com.alarmmanager;


import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainService extends Service 
{

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

     public void onCreate() {

         Log.i("nilavs","nilav");
         Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.alarmmanager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service
            android:name=".MainService"
            android:enabled="true"
        />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmReceiver">

</receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code?

Comment: yes it says:- the source attachment does not contain the source for the file classLoader.class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620294/how-to-attach-android-source-to-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getBroadcast` instead of `getService`?

```
PendingIntent pending =PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

**Edit:**

Try setting it to fire off in the future initially - e.g.

```
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+5000,15000,pending);
```

Comment: sorry but I am still facing the same problem